# PHP form not sending GET

Tags: php, forms, get

So I'm working on a searchfunction for my webwshop and I've gotten pretty far. I've set the GET function up with the SELECT code on the search.php file. So I "pretty confidently" thought lets just quickly do the form and I'm done....

Well not so easy as it turns out. I've got this code now and I can't seem to send the data with the get. When you search something now all you get is http://buitenlandseproducten.nl/search.php?id= but nothing stored in the id.

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 text-center"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o bigicon"></i></span>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input id="form" name="form" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <?php
        echo '<p>'. '<a href="search.php?id='.$_POST['form'].'">' . '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">' . 'Search' . '</button>' . '</a>' . '<br />';
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

If someone could help me out here you'll be my hero forever!
Help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You don't have a form tag.  You have a text element.

Comment: and where's this coming from? `$_POST['form']` not enough code here and you're not checking for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="GET" action="search.php">
<input id="form" name="id" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" />
<input type='Submit' Value="Search!"/>
</form>
```

This should give you what i want.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 text-center"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o bigicon"></i></span>
    <div class="col-md-8">
         <form method="GET" action="search.php">
<input id="form" name="id" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" />
<input type='Submit' Value="Search!"/>
</form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <?php
       // I don't know why you have this echo below here, its not necessary for what you're trying 
// echo '<p>'. '<a href="search.php?id='.$_POST['form'].'">' . '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">' . 'Search' . '</button>' . '</a>' . '<br />';
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The href element to link to the search.php and create a get field and assign a value to it from A POST field is kind of stretching it, and not a real smart way to go about doing it. 
Good luck to you, you'll need it :)

Comment: Omg you are my hero O.o. The way with the href is the way I learned it at school so I din't know beter... I've used it for the profuct page in the way of     '<a href="product.php?id='.$row['ArtikelNr'].'">' so I thought I could just change the row into a post. And I forgot the whole form tags. I may should go and clear my head. Thanks you so much!!! I wish I could give you coockies!!

Comment: You can use an href element when you want to link to a product that uses GET fields to read the ID and fetch necessary data. 

For something like a search feature, you need to get input from a user, and then send it to a script as a GET field.  Grabbing the value of a GET field is pretty much the same in both cases, just the processing of the data changes.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you for your help! And sorry for my drowsiness :P

Answer (score 1):

You mixed GET and POST:

```
<form action="/search.php" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
         <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 text-center"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o bigicon"></i></span>
         <div class="col-md-8">
             <input id="form" name="form" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" >
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-12 text-center">


<?php
    // check if the parameter is set.
    if (isset($_GET['form'])) {
        echo '<p><a href="search.php?id='.urlencode($_GET['form']).'"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Search</button></a><br />';
    }
  ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah I kinda screwed up... I may need some sleep or something I even forgot the form tags >.< Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if your $_POST['form'] is not set. Using $_POST like that means that you're accessing a form after being on another page with a form. is that normal? It doesn't feel normal. Especially not when it's not secured with strip_tags or htmlentities.
If you want help, you need to show the other form page's code because that is where the problem is.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_POST_method

Comment: Yeah I totally forgot to set the form... Idk how and why but I did... Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<form action="/search.php" method="GET">
  <div class="form-group">
    <span class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 text-center"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o bigicon"></i></span>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input id="form" name="id" type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <?php
        echo '<p>'. '<a href="search.php?id='.$GET['id'].'">' . '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">' . 'Search' . '</button>' . '</a>' . '<br />';
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```